# Xbox, PS3, Wii Parental lock API/SDK

Tags: sdk, playstation3, xbox, wii

Sorry if this is a general question but I cannot locate this information (their SDK's are mostly locked)

Do the SDKs for Xbox, PS3, Wii have an API/access to parental lock facility? Can I make an app that can control the parental lock on these machines?

Thanks
- Sami

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the Wii, if you mean you are using DevkitPro (as I believe the official SDKs are long out of use and not allowed to be publicly discussed), then it is possible to find and modify this information through the [/shared2/sys/SYSCONF](https://wiibrew.org/wiki//shared2/sys/SYSCONF#IPL.PC) file.

Unfortunately I am not familiar with homebrew for the other 2 systems though...

Comment: Oh. Ok did not notice the year until now. Sorry for the necropost...